# How to overlay a relative positioned div with a background color

Tags: jquery, css, dom, layout

While working on a project I noticed some behavior which has me confused. I was adding a popup window that greys out the background using jQuery fadeIn() to overlay a div with a grey transparent background color (pretty sure you know what I'm describing). I noticed that the div overlayed the whole page except for a div that with relatively positioned AND had a background color. It was like this div was resting on top of the div that I called fadeIn() on.

This is a simple example of an element that will not be overlayed:

```
#container {
    position:relative;
    background: white;
    border: .1em solid black
}
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eT2Lz/166/) with a simple example of what I'm talking about.

If you remove the background property OR the relative positioning property it works. I'd like to know what work arounds there are, but more importantly I'm curious *why* this is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `z-index` to have the overlay go over any positioned elements.

The changed css:

```
#block {
    background: #000;
    opacity:0.6;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    display:none;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Finally, here is a fiddle: [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eT2Lz/167/)

Here is some info about [`z-index`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)

Comment: Arg so obvious. I actually tried setting the z-index of the container to 0 so I was _almost_ there. Thank a lot dude.

Comment: No problem mate! You were close but luckily it is solved now. :]

Answer (score 0):

try to give to the overlay DIV an high z-index because if both have `position:relative` z-index might fix your ptoblem.

Answer (score 0):

This is about the element `#container`  is to `#block`, so that appears above it. You can just set the CSS `z-index` and it is.

```
#block {
   background: #000;
   opacity:0.6;
   position: fixed;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top:0;
   left:0;
   display:none;
   z-index: 10;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Pesulap/eT2Lz/171/)